# JFrame appears blank after swapping JFrames twice (using Intellij GUI designer)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm relatively new to Java Swing in general and decided to use Intellij's GUI Designer. For those not familiar with it, Intellij creates 2 files for each GUI "screen". One is the "design" in the form of a `.form` file where you drag and drop UI components, and one is the "controller".

Anyway, I'm doing a 5-step questionnaire implemented on Java Swing. The first part asks the user what is their favourite fruit, and when a choice button is clicked, the choice is saved and the next JFrame appears with the next question and so on. JFrame1 transitioning to JFrame2 worked fine, and all UI components were shown. However, when I tried to transition from JFrame2 to JFrame3, JFrame3 showed up blank instead.

[image: Empty JFrame at second transition]

I've tried to call `.pack()` before `setVisible(true)`, and then calling `.toFront()` after that, but that didn't help.

Below shows a section of my code. **JFrame1, 2, and 3 all use the same exact code in its constructors and calling of the next JFrame. JFrame1 only differs by a single line which will be stated later in the code.**

**JFrame1.java**

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame {
    private JPanel mainPanel;
    private JLabel narrationLabel;
    private JButton option1_btn;
    private JButton option2_btn;
    private JButton option3_btn;

    public Frame1()
    {
        setTitle("Questionnaire");
        setSize(1000, 1000);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        Frame2 nextScreen = new Frame2 (); //declare the next screen to show

        add(mainPanel); //this is only for the first starting JFrame
                        //JFrame2 and JFrame3 do not have this

        //repeat this for buttons option2_btn and option3_btn
        option1_btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
                //swap screens to the next main filler selection screen
                mainPanel.setVisible(false);
                nextScreen.pack();                
                add(nextScreen.getPanel());
                nextScreen.getPanel().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public JPanel getPanel() 
    {
        return mainPanel;
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame1 frame1 = new JFrame1(); //create start screen GUI
                frame1.setVisible(true); //display GUI
            }
        });
    }
}
```

My hunch tells me it *might* a concurrency issue, but I'm not sure if I am right, or where is the issue and how to resolve it. If a `.form` file is needed, I would gladly upload the code for it. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Hi, so first off, this is something that's really hard to recreate without the full code, so if you want quick and good help, give us code samples that compile and replicate the error you encountered. Second off, I wouldn't solve your problem the way you're trying to. Something like a questionnaire where you go from "frame to frame" shouldn't be done with opening and discarding frames. Check out [Card Layout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), I think that will get you to your destination a lot faster and easier!

Comment: @yur *"if you want quick and good help, give us code samples that compile and replicate the error"* Great idea, and a tip: Put `[mre]` in a comment, and it will automatically expand to [mre].

Comment: @yur Oh I wasn't aware about Cardlayout because the tutorial I saw told me to do the way I did. Is it easy to migrate over to CardLayout, or is it something like a complete overhaul?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Oh, great tip, thanks! I'm starting to up my SE game lately, so that tip will surely help haha!

Comment: @Cheryl Well, it won't be a complete overhaul, since you have the base code and gui pretty much ready to go, you will just need to copy + paste some code to some other places. I'm pretty sure you will end up with less time spent and grey hairs grown if you just start utilising a CardLayout right now!

Comment: @AndrewThompson Thanks for the info, I think I'll try my hand at converting to CardLayout first. But I'll certainly keep that in mind for future questions, thanks!

Comment: @yur Thanks for the headsup, think I'll try that and save myself some frustration in the long run :)